# Finger movement detection devices

Tags: switches, detection, movement

Let's consider a device such as a [game controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_controller) or a standard [remote control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_control), but which is not controlled by "standard" keys. Instead, the idea is to minimize finger movement, such as in a [keyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyer). What would be the best way to detect rather small finger movements - things like these come to my mind:

- [TPA511GLFS](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/CK-Components/TPA511GLFS/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsFLoxuNbFfpZSqvE2WXbJNVt%252bgNDGx32c%3d)

[image]

- [JS1300AQ](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/E-Switch/JS1300AQ/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsFLoxuNbFfpSD5be6ax7Cfndsjf8p84s8%3d)

[image]

Some notes on what I'm thinking about:

- Doesn't necessary need to be a mechanical device
- It would be good to support more then 4 / 5 directions - e.g. 9-way (i.e. w, nw, n, ne, e, se, s, sw + down) would be much better
- While I'd like to hear experiences about these types, it would be better to have a way to either prevent or at least detect accidental "typing"
- Obviosly, finger movement is the variable to minimize - I'd say 1/2" would be the threshold here
- Let me know if I'm thinking in the wrong direction (too hard? better in some other way? etc.)

I'm mostly looking at your past experience in this area:

- Did you ever have to build / maintain anything remotely similar?
- Why would or would not you use the same component / process?
- How did the final product turn out (e.g. in terms of ease of use)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use capacitive sensing. It is non-mechanical and could be used for any surface shape (in theory). A tiny array of sensors may deliver the resolution you need. Accidental typing could be detected by requiring unlikely touch combinations or having a locked mode, like on (old) mobile phones.

Comment: Thanks Suha! Do you have a recommendation about the discrete electronic part that can be used?